# Autolayout for UIButton in table view cell not working

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout, autolayout, adaptive-layout

I have added UIButton to my table view cell with autolayout but UIButton height constraint not working (Already set >=)

[image]

Below is my autolayout constraint settings,

[image]

Below is the xib design of cell,

[image]

Comment: what row height are you giving to UITableView cell?

Comment: you use static / dynamic ?? , see relevant Code

Comment: Added dynamic height to the UITableView cell

Comment: , any way it's intrinsic size should work

Comment: @Sh_Khan , not getting you can you suggest me some kind of link or some thing?

Comment: post your autolatout code

Comment: show your constraints... obviously problem is in your setting and not in autolayout

Comment: can you screen shoot design xib

Comment: from the screenshot it seems that you got exactly what you specified.. what is your problem?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ, the problem is in first screenshot.

Comment: the first screenshot looks exactly like your prototype, it just does not adapt to button texts

Comment: yes, I think button size constrain not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement your own `UIButton` subclass that would provide what you want. You can use following `TitleAdaptingButton` implementation, it overrides `intrinsicContentSize` to adapt to the text in title label even in vertical axis:

```
class TitleAdaptingButton: UIButton {

    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            if !oldValue.equalTo(bounds) {
                invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
            }
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        get {
            let labelSize = titleLabel!.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: frame.width - (titleEdgeInsets.left + titleEdgeInsets.right), height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
            let desiredButtonSize = CGSize(width: labelSize.width + contentEdgeInsets.left + contentEdgeInsets.right, height: labelSize.height + contentEdgeInsets.top + contentEdgeInsets.bottom)
            return desiredButtonSize
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        // if you want the text centered
        //        self.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        // if you want the text centered
        //        self.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    }
}
```

Once you add this class into your project, just set it as a custom class for each of your buttons:

[image]

But remember, for the buttons to adapt, the cell has to be allowed to define its own size, so you have to use following on your `tableView`:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44 // or your better estimation
```